# My app is blocked using Google Strategy with PassportJs and MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, passport.js

i develop an app using MERN stack and PassportJs for authentication. I used Google strategy to allow user authentication but i'm faced issues.

Here are the errors that appear in the console:

> Access to fetch at 'https://tagsite.herokuapp.com/users/google' from origin 'https://tagsite.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> GET https://tagsite.herokuapp.com/users/google net::ERR_FAILED

How can i fix it? Some help please.

I already use cors package in backend, but still have same errors.

Here is my code.

***Backend***

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');

if (process.env.NODE_END !== 'production') {
    // Load environment variables from .env file for non production environment
    require('dotenv').config()
}

// Connect database
require('./utils/connectdb')

// Strategies
require('./strategies/GoogleStrategy')

require('./utils/authenticate')

// Routes import
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET))

app.use(cors())
app.use(passport.initialize())

// Use routes
app.use('/users', userRoutes)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ status: 'success' })
})

// Server set up
let port;
if (process.env.PORT) {
    port = process.env.PORT
} else {
    port = 8000
}

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listen on port: ' + port)
})

module.exports.handler = serverless(app)
```

**GoogleStrategy.js**

```
const passport = require('passport')
    const googleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
    const User = require('../models/user')
    const slug = require('slug')
    require('dotenv').config()

    // serialize & deserialize user
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id)
        // done(null, user)
    })

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id)
        .then((user) => {
            done(null, user)
        })
        // done(null, user)
    })

    passport.use(
        new googleStrategy(
            {
                clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_SECRET,
                callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CALLBACK_URL
            },
            (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                User.findOne({ providerId: profile.id })
                .then((user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        const userData = {
                            username: profile.displayName,
                            provider: profile.provider,
                            providerId: profile.id,
                            email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            avatar: profile._json.picture
                            && profile._json.picture,
                            token: accessToken,
                            slug: slug(profile.displayName)
                        }
                        user.refreshToken.push({ refreshToken: accessToken })
                        user.save()
                        done(null, userData)
                    } else {
                        new User({
                            username: profile.displayName,
                            provider: profile.provider,
                            providerId: profile.id,
                            email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            avatar: profile._json.picture
                            && profile._json.picture,
                            $addToSet: { refreshToken: accessToken },
                            slug: slug(profile.displayName)
                        })
                        .save()
                        .then((user) => {
                            const userData = {
                                username: profile.displayName,
                                provider: profile.provider,
                                providerId: profile.id,
                                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                                avatar: profile._json.picture
                                && profile._json.picture,
                                token: accessToken,
                                slug: slug(profile.displayName)
                            }
                            user.refreshToken.push({ refreshToken: accessToken })
                            user.save()
                            done(null, userData)
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(`create new user failed: ${error}`)
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        )
    )
```

**user.js (controllers)**

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {
    googleLogin: [
        passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
    ],

    googleLoginCallback : [
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            failureRedirect: process.env.AUTH_FAILURE_REDIRECT_URL,
            session: false
        }),
        (req, res, next) => {
            const token = req.user.token
            // res.status(200).json({userData: req.user})
            res.cookie('refreshToken', req.user.token, COOKIE_OPTIONS)
            res.send({ success: true, token })
        }
    ],
```

**user.js (routes)**

```
const router = require('express').Router()

// Controllers
const {
    googleLogin, googleLoginCallback
} = require('../controllers/user')

router.get('/google', googleLogin)
router.get('/google/callback', googleLoginCallback)

module.exports = router
```

***Frontend***

**google.js (component)**

```
import { Button, Callout } from '@blueprintjs/core'
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../../utils/context/UserContext'

const GoogleLogin = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [userContext, setUserContext] = useContext(UserContext)

    const loginGoogle = () => {
        setError(null)

        const genericErrorMessage = 'Something error'

        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users/google`, {
            method: 'GET',
            // credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
        })
            .then(async (res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    if (res.status === 400) {
                        setError('Please try again')
                    } else if (res.status === 401) {
                        setError('Unauthorized')
                    } else {
                        setError(genericErrorMessage)
                    }
                } else {
                    const data = await res.json()
                    setUserContext((oldValues) => {
                        return { ...oldValues, token: data.token }
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(genericErrorMessage)
            })
    }

    return (
        <>
            {error && <Callout intent="danger">{error}</Callout>}
            <Button text="login with google" onClick={loginGoogle} />
        </>
    )
}

export default GoogleLogin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
"https://tagsite.netlify.app"
   ],
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  })
);
```

Like your error is saying, CORS doesn't like your Front End Code. It doesnt know it. You have to introduce your Front End to your Backend, and tell your Backend to let certain origins access your server.

I'm not experienced enough on whether you have to include credentials or not, but it works for me!

Comment: DrakeColman, i tried your code but still having same errors.

Comment: Finally found an tutorial which use [Twitter](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0). I updated it to use google in my case. Everything works in local but not when i deployed it on heroku for backend and netlify for frontend.

Comment: After many searches, i finally solved my issues, using react-google-login and react-facebook-login packages. Thanks!